# What do t, n mean in python byte to string conversion?

Tags: python-3.x, string, hex, bytecode, string-conversion

I am trying to use struct library in python 3. When I use

```
import struct
struct.pack('h',10)
```

the output is

```
b'\n\x00'
```

When I input 9 instead of 10 the output is

```
b'\t\x00'
```

I wonder what t and n mean. From 11 to 15 the outputs are b to f.

Comment: \t is a tab char and \n is a new line char

Comment: Any idea why I get that output for 9,10 but the output seems fine from 11.(11 gives b'\x0b\x00', 12 gives output b'\x0c\x00'

Comment: not all ascii control chars are represented with a backslash char, 9 is tab and 10 is new line, these have backslash chars \t and \n, 11 is vertical tab and 12 is form feed control chars these dont have a bascklash code to represent them so for these you just get the hex output of that char which the hex code of 11 is 0b and for 12 is 0c

Comment: @ChrisDoyle Thank you

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I don't know why but you can  define strings like '\v\f' in python but it will be printed as '\x0b\x0c'.